# Trying to play sound when an iPhone is on silent in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, silent

I'm trying to allow me sound to be played even if the user has got their device on silent, i have looked everywhere on how to do this and can't find the result I'm looking for! I'm using Xcode 5 and iOS 7.1 as my build. Any help would be amazing !

Comment: Your users will not thank you for playing sounds when they have set their phones to silent.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is meant to help guide you, not write your code for you.

Comment: @PaulR my application is a soundboard so it will be helpful when they press the button as i am getting complaints about the sound not playing and i have told the users that their device has to be off silent, so by bringing this out in an update it will stop this complaint.

Comment: @esqew I can't find anything that works at all ! I know the site is suppose to help and not write the code but if i could get some help on finding where I could find on how to do this,

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." ([Source](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick answer is: no, there is no way to detect if the mute switch is on though public API.

It has been a "way" to do this. If a 3 second sound whose length is nearly 0 in completion block, it is assumed it is set to mute mode.

But I wouldn't rely on that and instead:

Why not just implement a way in your App to let your users know that when their phone is on mute, no sound is played? Just like they warn people that the hot coffee is hot, which may cause burns?